# How can I dismiss an overCurrentContext modal viewController and its children?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following structure:

- From `mainVC` I present a modal viewController, `modalVC`:

  ```
  let modalVC: ModalVC = ModalVC()
  modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
  modalVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
  self.present(modalVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
  ```
- From `modalVC` I present another viewController `chatVC`, but this time without the `.overCurrentContext` option:

  ```
  let chatVC: ChatVC = ChatVC()
  self.present(chatVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
  ```

At this point, I have the following:

`mainVC` --present modally --> `modalVC` --present--> `chatVC`

I want to dismiss `chatVC` and `modalVC` to show `mainVC` again.

I tried:

```
self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

No succeed.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController is mainVC.

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes help to be a little verbose... helps to understand what's going on vs. what you expect to be going on. Try it like this:

```
    if let myPresenter = self.presentingViewController {

        if let hisPresenter = myPresenter.presentingViewController {

            hisPresenter.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        }

    }
```

If that doesn't "work" you can at least step through in debug to figure out what's not quite right.